# Jquery Event Delegation Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Can anyone suggest where I'm going wrong here? `news_active` is a static div, everything else is loaded in via ajax calls, nothing is being triggered for the alert, pretty stumped?!

```
$('#news_active').load('ajax.php', function() {
    // Delete news active
    $('#news_delete').on('click', function() {
        var vNid = $('#news_delete').attr('data-nid').val();
        alert(vNid);
        //$('#news_active').load('ajax.php?nid='+vNid);
    });
});
```

The button looks like this, there are multiple buttons loaded in with different data-nid values:

```
<button id="news_delete" data-nid="1">Delete</button>
```

Comment: @oGeez There are multiple buttons, updated the question, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `news_delete` is loaded dynamically, you need to use [`event delegation`](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to register the event handler like:

```
// New way (jQuery 1.7+) - .on(events, selector, handler)
$('#news_active').on('click', '#news_delete', function(event) {
    var vNid = $('#news_delete').data('nid');
    alert(vNid); 
});
```

Also, the way of getting the `data-nid` attribute value in your code is not correct.

Either use this:

```
var vNid = $('#news_delete').attr('data-nid');  // No need of .val() here
alert(vNid);
```

or just this using [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

```
var vNid = $('#news_delete').data('nid');  
alert(vNid);
```

Comment: No need as `load()` method callback will fire after HTML insertion was performed, see http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method instead:

```
var vNid = $('#news_delete').data('nid');
```

or just `attr('data-nid')` without `val()`.

[`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is trying to get `Element.value` property and you don't have it in `button`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var vNid = $('#news_delete').attr('data-nid').val(); //remove the value it 
                                              // will return the value of button
```

change it to

```
var vNid = $('#news_delete').attr('data-nid');
```